# Integrating a non-threaded SQLAlchemy code with Flask-SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a python module UserManager that takes care for all things user management related - users, groups, rights, authentication. Access to these assets is provided via master class that is passed SQLAlchemy engine parameter at constructor. The engine is needed to make the table-class mappings (using mapper objects), and to emit sessions.

This is how the gobal variables are established in the app module:

```
class UserManager:

    def __init__(self, db):
        self.db = db
        self._db_session = None
        meta = MetaData(db)

        user_table = Table(
            'USR_User', meta,
            Column('field1'),
            Column('field3')
        )
        mapper(User, user_table)

    @property
    def db_session(self):
        if self._db_session is None:
            self._db_session = scoped_session(sessionmaker())
            self._db_session.configure(bind=self.db)
        return self._db_session

class User(object):
    def init(self, um):
        self.um = um

from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
um = UserManager(db.engine)
```

This module as such is designed to be context-agnostic by purpose, so that it can be used both for locally run and web application.

But here the problems arise: time to time I get the dreaded "Can't reconnect until invalid transaction is rolled back" error, presumably caused by some failed transaction in the UserManager code.

I am now trying to identify the problem source. Maybe it is not right way how to handle the database in the dynamic context of web server? Perhaps I have to pass the db.session to the um object so that I can be sure that the db connections are not mixed up?

Answer (score 0):

In web context you should consider the request for every user isolated. For  this you must use the `flask.g`

> To share data that is valid for one request only from one function to
>   another, a global variable is not good enough because it would break
>   in **threaded environments**.Flask provides you with a special object
>   that ensures it is only valid for the active request and that will
>   return different values for each request. In a nutshell: it does the
>   right thing, like it does for request and session.

You can see more about [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#application-globals).